# Terminator not loading .bashrc or .vimrc

Tags: vim, terminal, gnome-terminal, terminator

I installed `Terminator` using following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-terminator
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

It seems like it's not loading `.bashrc` file. When I open `Vim` in terminator, it's not even loading `.vimrc` file.
I can't even change `Preferences`->`Profile`->`Colors`.

But everything is working fine in `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click on the terminator window and select `preferences`.
On `profiles` tab, tick check `Run command as login shell`.
This will enable terminator to read the `rc` files on startup.